# How to Avoid Duplicate tabs in child MDI Tab Control

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I am using .NET 3.5 with c# winforms. in this i am using MDI child tab control. it works fine if i open a form, it will open successfully. if i open same form again it opens. that means duplication of tabs.

My code is like below...

```
private void Main_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
                tabForms.Visible = false; // If no any child form, hide tabControl
            else
            {
                this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // Child form always maximized

                if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
                {
                    TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
                    tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                    tp.Parent = tabForms;
                    tabForms.SelectedTab = tp;

                    this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
                    this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(ActiveMdiChild_FormClosed);
                }

                if (!tabForms.Visible) tabForms.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

in this, every time this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag takes the value of null so it opens new form again and again. that means duplication of forms in tab control

Comment: A tabbed windowing model compares to MDI like water compares to fire.  Use one or the other, not both.

Answer (score 0):

Add the above method in order to check if the form with the name is as child in the mdi parent.

```
  public static bool FormExist(string formName, out Form frm)
    {
        frm = null;
        bool exist = false;

        Form[] f = yourMdiParent.ActiveForm.MdiChildren;
        foreach (Form ff in f)
        {
            if (ff.Name == formName)
            {
                frm = ff;
                exist = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return exist;
    }
```

and add the check on adding the child form.

```
   Form forma;
   if(FormExist("yourchildformid",out forma) && forma !=null)
   {
      forma.Focus();
      return;
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this method can be static since you need to access an instance variable? Also, why not return Form and then return null if not found or the actual Form if found.

Comment: In the class i use it i just have static. You can change it. If return null then you initialize it and add it to mdi parent. This piece of code working properly in my erp for years. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I use:

```
    private void serviceManagerToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // prevent duplicates
        if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<ServiceManager>().FirstOrDefault() != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        ServiceManager serviceManager = new ServiceManager { MdiParent = this, WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized };
        serviceManager.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work with a few tweeks by combining other solutions

add this function to your Parent MDI Form

```
    private bool checkTabExists(string tabVal)
    {
        foreach (TabPage tab in tabForms.TabPages)
        {
            if (tab.Text == tabVal)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Then Modify the original Form_MdiChildActivate to include an additional check

```
    private void Main_MdiChildActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.ActiveMdiChild == null)
            tabForms.Visible = false; // If no any child form, hide tabControl
        else
        {
            this.ActiveMdiChild.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized; // Child form always maximized

            if(checkTabExists(this.ActiveMdiChild.Name))
            {
                //If the Child Form already Exists Go to it
                foreach (TabPage tab in tabForms.TabPages)
                {
                    if (tab.Text == this.ActiveMdiChild.Name)
                        tabForms.SelectedTab = tab;
                }

            }
            // If child form is new and has no tabPage, create new tabPage
            else if (this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag == null)
            {
                ActiveMdiChild.TopLevel = false;
                ActiveMdiChild.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                ActiveMdiChild.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;

                // Add a tabPage to tabControl with child form caption
                TabPage tp = new TabPage(this.ActiveMdiChild.Text);
                tp.Tag = this.ActiveMdiChild;
                tp.Parent = tabForms;
                tabForms.SelectedTab = tp;

                this.ActiveMdiChild.Tag = tp;
                this.ActiveMdiChild.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(Main_FormClosed);
            }

            if (!tabForms.Visible) tabForms.Visible = true;
            //tabForms.AutoSize = true;
            //tabForms.TabPages[0].Height = 38;

        }
    }
```